# Direct terminal output to Mysql table

Tags: mysql, linux, database, phpmyadmin

I want to send the output of this Linux command to MySql table:
Command:

```
bzcat filename.bz2 | head -200 | cut -f2,13-15,17 | ruby -ne 'puts "#{$_}" if $_ =~ /\s\d+\.\d+/; ' | ruby -ne 'puts "#{$_}"' | cut -f1-5
```

Command Text Output:

```
6985418911  -81.804885  24.550558   12  http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7205/6985418911_df7747990d.jpg

10201275523 -79.365637  43.649708   16  http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5465/10201275523_3e6ea67c7f.jpg

7289030198  -73.985495  40.740067   15  http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7231/7289030198_1f1ba44113.jpg

4572998878  -71.047843  42.33719    16  http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3373/4572998878_658b45226f.jpg

3973434963  -0.384016   39.474441   15  http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2526/3973434963_76c26e3c88.jpg

2932067831  -109.4995   38.737861   16  http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3026/2932067831_8885c3d53f.jpg
```

The fields URL, Autotags and Photo/Video needs to be empty at this point.

Comment: Not without writing some application or script no.

Comment: That's good example. Would you mind, instead of pictures, paste the text of that command output (add 4 spaces in front of each line to format properly). It will make it easier to replicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to format the output as an INSERT statement so Mysql knows what do with it. You will have to have a table to catch the output as well. The schema is up to you. A simple example would be:

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE test;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> use test;
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE stdout_dump (line VARCHAR(5000));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.18 sec)

mysql> exit
Bye
```

Now you can format your output using `sed` or `awk` or what-have-you and pipe to mysql:

```
$ seq 1 10 | sed -r "s/(.*)/INSERT INTO test.stdout_dump VALUES ('\1');/g" | mysql -u youruser -p
```

And the values will be loaded into your table:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test.stdout_dump;
+------+
| line |
+------+
| 1    |
| 2    |
| 3    |
| 4    |
| 5    |
| 6    |
| 7    |
| 8    |
| 9    |
| 10   |
+------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Or:

```
$ echo "this is another line" | sed -r "s/(.*)/INSERT INTO test.stdout_dump VALUES ('\1');/g" | mysql -u yourusername -p

mysql> SELECT * FROM test.stdout_dump;
+----------------------+
| line                 |
+----------------------+
| 1                    |
| 2                    |
| 3                    |
| 4                    |
| 5                    |
| 6                    |
| 7                    |
| 8                    |
| 9                    |
| 10                   |
| this is another line |
+----------------------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

Here's an example with a more complex schema (multiple columns in the table). Again this really comes down to using `awk` or `sed` or what-have-you on the command line to generate INSERT statements for your table that you can pipe to mysql:

```
$ cat testoutput
10201275523 -79.365637  43.649708   16  http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5465/10201275523_3e6ea67c7f.jpg
7289030198  -73.985495  40.740067   15  http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7231/7289030198_1f1ba44113.jpg
4572998878  -71.047843  42.33719    16  http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3373/4572998878_658b45226f.jpg
3973434963  -0.384016   39.474441   15  http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2526/3973434963_76c26e3c88.jpg
2932067831  -109.4995   38.737861   16  http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3026/2932067831_8885c3d53f.jpg

$ cat testoutput | awk  '{printf "INSERT INTO test.Images (Hash, Lng, Lat, Accuracy, URL) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,'\''%s'\'');\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5}' | mysql -u yourusername -p
```

mysql> SELECT * FROM test.Images;

```
+------+-------------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+----------+----------+-------------+
| id   | Lng         | Lat       | URL                                                           | Hash        | Autotags | Accuracy | Photo/Video |
+------+-------------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+----------+----------+-------------+
| NULL |  -79.365637 | 43.649708 | http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5465/10201275523_3e6ea67c7f.jpg | 10201275523 | NULL     |       16 |        NULL |
| NULL |  -73.985495 | 40.740067 | http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7231/7289030198_1f1ba44113.jpg  |  7289030198 | NULL     |       15 |        NULL |
| NULL |  -71.047843 | 42.337190 | http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3373/4572998878_658b45226f.jpg  |  4572998878 | NULL     |       16 |        NULL |
| NULL |   -0.384016 | 39.474441 | http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2526/3973434963_76c26e3c88.jpg  |  3973434963 | NULL     |       15 |        NULL |
| NULL | -109.499500 | 38.737861 | http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3026/2932067831_8885c3d53f.jpg  |  2932067831 | NULL     |       16 |        NULL |
+------+-------------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+----------+----------+-------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

It would be a good idea to spend some time familiarizing yourself with `sed` and `awk` as well as `mysql` INSERT statements if you will be doing this work often.

Comment: Please have a look at my Linux command: `bzcat filename.bz2 | head -200 | cut -f2,13-15,17 | ruby -ne 'puts "#{$_}" if $_ =~ /\s\d+\.\d+/; ' | ruby -ne 'puts "#{$_}"' | cut -f1-5`                                                  Database Name: YFkr , Table Name: Images, Fields (Hash, Lng, Lat, Accuracy, URL). I can not direct output of above command to my table.

Comment: Perhaps if you can share (back up in your question) a sample output from your command and your table's DDL we can assist further. I'm certain it can be done, although it might get ugly depending on what that output looks like and the field types of your table.

Comment: Have a look please!

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example that is close to what you are dealing with. In this second answer I use `awk` to parse the output from your complex command into `INSERT` statements that are then piped to mysql. There is no magic bullet here where you can just blindly pipe into a mysql command. There will always need to be something between your output and `mysql ` to transform the data into `INSERT` statements that `mysql` can make sense of. And that "something" will have to be a script that you write. Here I've used both `sed` and `awk` one-liners to do that conversion.